# Swift programming in xcode

Tags: xcode6

When i open Xcode6 beta3 am getting this error. Can anyone tel the solution fa this.. Am using os x version 10.9.5.

Error:"Xcode 6-Beta 3 cannot be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed".

Comment: Why are you still using beta 3? The final version is available for download.

Comment: Do you allow apps downloaded from the Internet to be opened on your Mac, in System Settings?

Comment: Thank yu friends i got it..